# Toggle between panels

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, panels

I am trying to implement a solution that required to toggle between 2 independent panels, Sign In and Sign Up.

Each panel should have the following characteristics:
1- They are only displayed when a link in the navbar is clicked;
2- Only 1 of them should be displayed at any given moment, allowing to toggle between the links that activate them;
3- They should have a "X" link at the top right corner that allow to close the panel;
4- Either panel will retract if User click in the page content.

Here's the HTML:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-default">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a id="home"><!--HOME ANCHOR--></a>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/190x40" style="padding-top: 5px;" />
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-default">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a id="toggleSignInPanel" class="no-border noto-sans" href="#SignInPanel"><i class="fa fa-tablet padding-right-five-px"></i>Sign In</a></li>
                    <li><a id="toggleSignUpPanel" class="no-border noto-sans" href="#SignUpPanel"><i class="fa fa-tablet padding-right-five-px"></i>Sign Up</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <br />
    <br />

    <div id="upper">          
        <div id="SignInPanel">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"><h2>Sign In Left Panel</h2><img class="responsive-img" src="http://placehold.it/400x250" alt="Test Image 1" /></div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"><h2>Sign In Right Panel</h2><img class="responsive-img" src="http://placehold.it/400x250" alt="Test Image 2" /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="SignUpPanel">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"><h2>Sign Up Left Panel</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a mauris et nulla facilisis eleifend. Sed metus orci, vulputate sit amet malesuada id, luctus vestibulum lacus. Sed faucibus, nibh vel faucibus porta, lectus lacus suscipit metus, ut posuere nulla dolor porttitor erat.</p></div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"><h2>Sign Up Right Panel</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a mauris et nulla facilisis eleifend. Sed metus orci, vulputate sit amet malesuada id, luctus vestibulum lacus. Sed faucibus, nibh vel faucibus porta, lectus lacus suscipit metus, ut posuere nulla dolor porttitor erat.</p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="lower">
        <p>This is the remaining page content that should be pushed down to allow for either Sign In or Sign Up panel contents to be displayed accordingly. This is the remaining page content that should be pushed down to allow for either Sign In or Sign Up panel contents to be displayed accordingly.</p>
    </div>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
//Toggle Sign In Panel
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#toggleSignInPanel").click(function(){
        $("#SignInPanel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});

//Toggle Sign Up Panel
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#toggleSignUpPanel").click(function(){
        $("#SignUpPanel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

This is the JSFiddle that I have have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/qawccvbs/1/

Would anyone be able to help me out with this issue?  Thank you!

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to just call the api function to close all the other panels every time you toggle a new one open. (Also, you don't need to wrap every function in a new `document ready` call.)

```
//Toggle Panel
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toggleSignInPanel").click(function () {
        $("#SignInPanel").slideToggle("slow");
        $("#SignUpPanel").slideUp("slow");
    });
    $("#toggleSignUpPanel").click(function () {
        $("#SignInPanel").slideUp("slow");
        $("#SignUpPanel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

here's a new fiddle that closes the other panel when opening a new one:
http://jsfiddle.net/za1L1m77/

---

[edit:]

closing button is simple, you could just do the same thing as above:

```
$("#closingButton").click(function () {
    $("#SignInPanel").slideUp("slow");
    $("#SignUpPanel").slideUp("slow");
});
```

now, functionality for "click outside" of element is a little trickier because you have to listen to a click event on every element other than the toggles you have. One simple way to do this is to put a "toggle closed" event listener on window as a whole, and stop propogation on your toggle elements. Just keep in mind that you won't be able to put event listeners on parents of elements with stop propogation applied in the future and expect them to work:

```
$('html').click(function() {
    $("#SignInPanel").slideUp("slow");
    $("#SignUpPanel").slideUp("slow");
});
```

plus add this to all the toggles:

```
$("#toggleSignUpPanel").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#SignInPanel").slideUp("slow");
    $("#SignUpPanel").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: That is awesome! Thanks!

But how do I add a closing button, like a "X" at the top right corner and also have a functionality that closes whatever panels that is opened once the User clicks anywhere else in the screen, let's say the content below the panel?